# How to skip the next if statement without using return?

Tags: javascript

I have two if statements. One sets `this.node` to the next sibling of the parent node and the other one, sets `this.node` (recursively) to the last child of the next node.

```
if (!this.node.nextSibling) {
  this.node = findParentNode(this.node).nextSibling
}
if (this.node.nextSibling) {
  this.node = findNode(this.node.nextSibling)
}
```

From time to time, the two if statement will aftect each other, in other words, one will run and then the another one will run. I can't use `return` because that will stop the whole function (there's more code below).

How to do it so both statements don't interfere with each other?

Comment: @sp00m that's not necessarily correct, because the body of the first `if` *changes* `this.node`. *Maybe* it should be an `else`, but it's not at all clear what the OP wants to do.

Comment: You need to clarify your question, because I can not believe that you have 13.6k reputation here, and you not familiar with if/else statements or flags.

Comment: @lolka_bolka I know everything about if/else flags. Except how to stop two from executing without a `return` and a `else` statement.

Comment: Then what about @tjscience answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use an `else` statement combining both instead?

```
if (!this.node.nextSibling) {
  this.node = findParentNode(this.node).nextSibling
} else {
  this.node = findNode(this.node.nextSibling)
}
```

Comment: I'd probably reverse logic to simplify. No need to use a `not` operator.

Comment: What if, when he overwrite the this.node in the first statement? After this, the second could be true also, so try to figure out, what is OP really want.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply define a variable to determine if you should go into the second if block like so:

```
var wasProcessed = false;

if (!this.node.nextSibling) {
  this.node = findParentNode(this.node).nextSibling
  wasProcessed = true;
}
if (!wasProcessed && this.node.nextSibling) {
  this.node = findNode(this.node.nextSibling)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also put that IF condition in ELSE part of current(First IF).

```
if (!this.node.nextSibling) {
      this.node = findParentNode(this.node).nextSibling
    }
    else
    {
      if (this.node.nextSibling) {
        this.node = findNode(this.node.nextSibling)
        }
    }
```